# Change status on click jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Trying to change the status of font-awesome when checkbox is checked heart should change to red. Can't find the right thing to make it work.

can I click the heart and hide the checkbox? I know its something :before in the css but not entirely sure.

http://jsfiddle.net/xd8LbtLz/

```
$('.addToFav').click(function(){
    if($(this).prop('checked')){
        console.log('change heart to red');
    } else {
        console.log('do nothing atm');
    }
})
```

Comment: You didn`t connect jquery library in tour fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/xd8LbtLz/1/

Comment: Your logging is working fine after you add jQuery - http://jsfiddle.net/xd8LbtLz/2/

Comment: ^ i think he just didnt include the jquery script his code is working just fine

Comment: Heart is just an object but when clicked should change to red. This function is going to act as a "add to favourite" if you know what I mean.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xd8LbtLz/7/

Comment: well I know its working, just the logic that I couldn't find in my head.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, your fiddle did not include jQuery. Secondly, there's no point using `prop` to access a property of an element in a jQuery object when you can directly access the element itself. Lastly, you can use `toggleClass()` to add or remove a CSS class to change the colour of the hearts. Try this:

```
$('.addToFav').click(function () {
    $('.fa-heart').toggleClass('red', this.checked);
})
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/xd8LbtLz/5/)

Answer (score 0):

Few points

1) Your fiddle did not had jquery library included. which you need to include for using jq syntax.

2) Using change event is more appropriate in case of checkbox than click event.

3) use current checked property to set color to icon `.fa-heart`

```
$('.addToFav').change(function(){
   $(this).prev().css('color',this.checked ?  "red":"black");
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/w3qrgqn1/)**

Comment: cool thanks, but its checking all the hearts I need them to be checked individually though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use,

```
$('.addToFav').click(function() {
    if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
        $(this).prev().find("i").css("color", "red");
    } else {
        $(this).prev().find("i").css("color", "black");
    }
})
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/xd8LbtLz/6/)